# How do I solve unspecified error with cv2.imshow?

Tags: python, opencv, pip

My code keeps breaking only at points where I use the cv2.imshow() function. It displays this error:
**error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'**

It was working fine until after I installed another library, but I'm not sure how that would mess it up. I tried uninstalling that extra library but that didn't do anything to fix the issue. Any ideas? Some of the solutions I've found online are to install with pip install opencv-python, but that's how I installed it initially. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling opencv to no avail.

Additional details based on follow-up questions: I'm on a Windows computer using the Pycharm IDE, and I've been installing libraries using pip in the Miniconda app.

Here is what the code looks like. The error happens anytime I try to use imshow, so here's one example of code I run that causes the error:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("Tropical-tree.jpg")

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: @Yagoobean. Install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script. After that you will have to reinstall.

Comment: @toyotaSupra that's what I figured I was supposed to do from the error message, I'm just not sure how to haha

Comment: you can load the image in with OpenCV using the imread() function but then display the image with matplotlib. like 
`image= cv2.imread('Tropical-tree.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()`

Comment: @paulyang0125, I tried your advice but I'm not sure if I did it wrong because it didn't print anything (it said matplotlib doesn't have an imshow or show attribute)

Comment: the import should be `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference if anyone else has this issue, here's how I solved it

I had been using an environment I made in the Miniconda3 program. To fix the issue, I made a new environment (also in Miniconda) using this command:
`conda create --name new_env python=3.6`

Opencv works best with python 3.6 rather than the newest update, so it's important to specify the version when creating the environment. Then I went in the environment and reinstalled opencv using `pip install opencv-python`, and then in Pycharm I switched to use that environment and it worked fine. Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this!